# How to connect with PHP file in react native?

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native, ip

I am connecting in react native with php files (Back end) like this:

```
    componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('http://192.168.1.7:80/Encaissement.php',
    .....}
```

but the adresse ip is changing every time, so how to get directley current ip adress?(PS: I'm not using localhost because it gets me error with network)

OR how to replace 192.168.1.7 as variable and give it a valeur just in one page (because I have lot of pages and when I need to change ip adress I had to change it in like 15 pages)

Comment: Since just using `localhost` would generally be the best solution can you explain what exact issue you have with that? Maybe add the error message you get.

Are you running the web server on the same host as the browser?

Comment: when I had used localhost I get an error in my application saying :'' network request failed"  and when I googled it I found this solution(work with ipAdress.

Comment: What web server are you using and how is it configured, i.e. to listen on which IP/port?

Are you using reacts built-in dev server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure just in one site you can create a component and include it in your code when you need to fetch the data.

File GetIp.js

```
const getIp = () => { return 'http://192.168.1.7:80'; }

export default getIp;
```

Then when you need it yous just need to import it and use it

```
import getIp from './GetIp';

...
componentDidMount(){
  fetch(getIp() + '/Encaissement.php');   
}
```